# Why can't I have multiple authors after build (with poetry) in PKG-INFO?

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

- [x] I have searched the [issues](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues) of this repo and believe that this is not a duplicate.
- [x] I have searched the [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) and believe that my question is not covered.

### Issue

Hi I was wondering why there is only one author and author-email in the PKG-INFO file contained in the tar.gz archive of my package after building it with `poetry build`.

Part of my pyproject.toml :

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "Surikatz"
version = "1.1"
description = "A powerful tool for searching informations during pentest"
authors = ["alphae-nix <18laurent@gmail.com>", 
           "Anemys <abdelmalik_kerbadou@yahoo.fr>",
           "NathanSaucet <pro.nathan.saucet@gmail.com>",
           "Mogulzz <raayanb94@gmail.com>",
           "blackjack-nix <theo.peresse-gourbil@edu.esiee.fr>",
           "CappiLucky <manon.hermann@edu.esiee.fr>"
]
```

Part of the PKG-INFO file :

```
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: surikatz
Version: 1.1
Summary: A powerful tool for searching informations during pentest
Author: alphae-nix
Author-email: 18laurent@gmail.com
```

Comment: This is probably a bug. Maybe create an issue at https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry

Comment: Reason: https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-621-round-3/5472/87

Comment: @sinoroc thanks for the info, but it's still weird, why would you ouput the first one but still allow to have a list of authors in the toml ...

Plus, there is many projects made with several authors so there is no point to only output one of them ...

Comment: Agreed (I was the one to point it out in the discussion). That's how it is: the input format allows multiple but the output format allows one only. -- I guess the intention was to modify the output format at some point in order to allow multiple, but it has not happened yet.

Comment: On the other hand, it seems to me like the [`Author-email` field](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#author-email) can accommodate the content of your `authors`, so maybe that is what Poetry should use, I do not know.